# Angular 2 : Error while using directive *ng-for

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Just started working with Angular 2.0 beta version. I am getting error angular is not defined while adding `directive : [angular.ngFor]`.

Adding the Plunker url http://plnkr.co/edit/ULHddLRqPFXvNG7NPo93?p=preview

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ng-forOf' since it isn't a known native property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228971/cant-bind-to-ng-forof-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify the directive anymore since it's a core one. The name of the directive to use is `ngFor` instead of `ng-for`.

Your template:

```
<h2>{{teamName}}</h2>

<ul>
  {{players}}
  <li *ngFor="#player of players"> {{player}}</li>
</ul>
```

Your component:

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: 'app/home.html',
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {
        this.teamName = 'ManchesterUnited';
        this.players = ['Ronney','Mata','Depay','Jhones','Smalling','Schiderlin'];
      }
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

Since alpha.52 templates are case-sensitive. Use `ngFor` instead. This change also applies to other directives (`ngIf`, `ngModel`, ...)