# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

The element is `<div [ngIf]="isAuth" id="sidebar">`

And the component is:

```ts
import SessionService from '../session/session.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  providers: [],
  selector: 'navbar-left',
  styles: [require('./navbar-left.scss')],
  template: require('./navbar-left.html'),
})
export default class NavbarLeftComponent {
  public isAuth: boolean = false;

  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {
    this.isAuth = sessionService.sessionIsAuth();
  }
}
```

Not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong? This is a child component. In the parent component aka App component the `ngIf` works fine.
Angular RC5

Comment: make sure you aren't re-using a selector name, e.g.: `selector: 'duplicatedNameHere,`

Comment: Import "CommonModule" and DONT Forget to do "ng serve" twice to overcome the bad luck...

Comment: I had this error when I forgot to add my component to "Declarations" of my module.

Comment: Similar problem with Declarations thanks @MichaelWyraz

Comment: If you have such error in jasmine tests, make sure you have add tested component in declaration, like that "declarations: [MyComponent]" in spec file.

Comment: Sometimes it happens because of failed plugin in IDE (VS Code, Web Storm). Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70368326/4079915

Comment: if anyone using standalone component make sure to import commonModule to components as well  - imports:[CommonModule],

Comment: @MichaelWyraz i think this is the right answer for me :)

Comment: Check that you:
1) import CommonModule in the module that declares your component
2) import the module that declares your component in app.module.ts (or one of its imports). 

The Angular module system is ridiculous..

Answer (score 587, accepted):

If you are using RC5 then import this:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

and be sure to import `CommonModule` from the module that is providing your component.

```
 @NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [MyComponent]
  ...
})
class MyComponentModule {}
```

Comment: make sure your transpilation is working and you have the `*ngIf` in your code

Comment: error: cannot find name "CommonModule". I do import "BrowserModule" but it still generates the error "ngif isn't a known property

Comment: This answer only works for me if I add `export` to the class.

Comment: and don't forget about 'declarations'

Comment: I was getting a similar error and the fix was to add `BrowserModule` to `imports` in @NgModule

Comment: In case you still get the error after trying everything suggested in this page, try just to run "ng serve" once again.

Comment: Make sure that the module is also imported to your root `app.module.ts`

Comment: Make sure the child module with the problem is actually being imported by the parent module.

Comment: In my case,
I already had **CommonModule** included in my shared module & the feature module where the component was to be used, but in my case I saved some files while server was starting (compiling) maybe that's why it did not took registry of included modules properly

=> I restarted my local server it solved the problem for me

Comment: Similar issue. In my case I'd added the component to the module as a provider rather than in declarations. This stopped *ngIf and other things from working in the component.

Comment: Thanks @teddybear for the comment. You finally solved my problem.

Comment: If your component is standalone, you'll need to add `NgIf` or `CommonModule` to the imports array for @Component

Answer (score 585):

Just for anyone who still has an issue, I also had an issue where I typed `ngif` rather than `ngIf` (notice the capital 'I').

Comment: `nfIf` in my case, sometimes... :facepalm:

Comment: It can also happen if you write: *ngIf="{{condition}}". You must not write the {{ }}. *ngIf="condition" is working.

Comment: yes 80% people were using *ngif ---> ngIf

Comment: ngIf was a bad idea for naming, it should have been ngif , but strict nomenclatures standards forced the naming to be ngIf and ngFor instead of ngfor and ngif

Comment: The reason being is that this single comment has now 400 upvotes, so there have been many confused people who have lost at least 5 minutes trying to figure out what was wrong

Comment: I don't think "blaming camel case" is really accurate. 400 upvotes on a 5 year old post isn't that severe. I think it just indicates that people are accidentally typing typos. When I realized this it was not because I didn't know how to use ngIf, it was because of a typo. Same for most people here.

Comment: I was almost frustrated by trying all the ways like [BrowserModule], [CommonModule] etc., and finally the capital case "I" saved my day.

Comment: ngIF in my case :D

Comment: NgIf in my case :/

Comment: I was looking at my code an it said *ngIf* but an inner component had a *ngif*,

Comment: Its incredible how many people have found this comment useful, its by far my single most upvoted response. Glad it helped @fruitloaf

Comment: In my case was because I didnt add my Component into the module in declarations

Answer (score 59):

Instead of [ngIf] you should use *ngIf like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isAuth" id="sidebar">
```