# Set placeholder image if tag does not exist ionic 2 angular 2

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

When parsing rss feed in xml format, I display the images that are contained in the attibute `url` inside the tag `<enclosure>` but whenever the tag enclosure is missing because the article does not have an image, I'm getting an error in the console saying:

```
Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
```

I tried to solve this problem using `onError` function inside `src` but when the tag is missing I'm still getting the error in the console and the placeholder image is not shown.

Here's my `html` file:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title text-center>
      App Name
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let entry of entries" (click)="openPage(entry)" text-wrap>
      <ion-thumbnail>
        <img class="imgmg" src="{{entry.getElementsByTagName('enclosure')[0].getAttribute('url')}}" onError="this.src='assets/images/placeholder_image.png';" >
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2 class="title">{{entry.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].textContent}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I dont think you need that semi colon at the end there and shouldnt the img src be `[src]=`

Comment: @gerdi I actually edited those part but nothing changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*ngif`. example:

```
<img *ngIf="entry.getElementsByTagName('enclosure')[0].getAttribute('url')" class="imgmg" src="{{entry.getElementsByTagName('enclosure')[0].getAttribute('url')}}">
<img *ngIf="!entry.getElementsByTagName('enclosure')[0].getAttribute('url')" class="imgmg" src="assets/images/placeholder_image.png">
```

also check this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)

EDIT:

```
<img *ngIf="image_available" class="imgmg" src="{{entry.getElementsByTagName('enclosure')[0].getAttribute('url')}}">
<img *ngIf="!image_available" class="imgmg" src="assets/images/placeholder_image.png">
```

Comment: I added them both inside `<ion-thumbnail>` but I'm getting this error: 
`Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'img'.`

Comment: Check till where you got something and change ngif. I update the answer. please use the approach.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with @aminarghavani 's solution. You have to import the correct module (BrowserModule or CommonModule): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058075/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div

Comment: @aminarghavani @yadejo It seems that the first answer you gave me was correct! I just had to make one little modification, `*ngIf` instead of `*ngif`. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: "[src]=" is better used when dealing with dynamic/expression image sources