# can not able to access this.project.responsibility.Responsibility in html

Tags: angular

Here I am stuck on printing responsibility in the project. You can refer below json to see. I am not able to access this.project.responsibility.Responsibility in HTML. Please help me. I tried many ways to access it But I cant.Please tell how can we access array within array means inside array.

project.component.html

```
<p-dataList [value]="projects">
            <p-header>
                        projects
            </p-header>
    <ng-template let-project let-i="index" pTemplate="item">
            <div class="ui-g ui-fluid car-item">

                    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4" style="text-align:center">

                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-8 car-details">
                        <div class="ui-g">
                            <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6"><b>Project no {{i+1}}</b></div>
                            <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6"></div>

                            <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Customer Name:</div>
                            <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6"> {{ this.project.CustomerName }}</div> 
                            <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Responsibility: </div>
                            <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6">{{ this.project.responsibility.Responsibility }}</div>

                            <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">description:</div>
                            <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6">{{ this.project.responsibility.description }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
    </ng-template>
</p-dataList>
```

project.component.ts

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import * as jwt from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';
    import { CardModule } from 'primeng/card';
    import { ScrollPanelModule } from 'primeng/scrollpanel';
    import { PersonListService,Person, Project, ProjectResponsibility} from './person-list.service';
    import {DataListModule} from 'primeng/datalist';

    @Component({ 
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'sd-project',
      templateUrl: 'project.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['project.component.css']
    })
    export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {
      errorMessage: any;
      projects: Project[];
      projectresponsibilities:ProjectResponsibility[];

        constructor(public personListService:PersonListService){}
        ngOnInit() {
           // console.log(jwt.AuthConfig);

           this.getperson();
           console.log("creaea");
        }

        getperson(){

         this.personListService.getProject()
          .subscribe(
           resp => this.projects = resp.Projects,

            //resp => this.addresses = resp.Addresses,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
          );
     }
     }

person-list.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class Project{

    ProjectId:number;   
    CustomerName:string="";
    ProjectTitle:string="";
    ProjectType:string="";
    FromDate:Date;
    TodaysDate:Date;
    ProjectDescription:string="";
    Role:string="";
    ResponsibilityId:number;
    Responsibility:string="";
    Description:string="";

}

export class Person{
  Projects:Project [];
}

@Injectable()
export class PersonListService {

  /**
   * Creates a new NameListService with the injected HttpClient.
   * @param {HttpClient} http - The injected HttpClient.
   * @constructor
   */
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  /**
   * Returns an Observable for the HTTP GET request for the JSON resource.
   * @return {string[]} The Observable for the HTTP request.
   */

getProject(): Observable<{ Projects: Project[]}>{
    console.log("Inside the get service")
    return this.http.get('app/person/person.json')

                 // .do(data => console.log('server data:', data))  // debug
                    .catch(this.handleError);

  }
   * Handle HTTP error
    */
  private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

person.json

```
{
"Projects": [

    {
        "ProjectId":1,  
        "CustomerName":"Abc Company",
        "ProjectTitle":"Website",
        "ProjectType":"Educational",
        "FromDate":"2/2011",
        "ToDate":"2/2012",
        "ProjectDescription":"It is the college website",
        "Role":"Data analysis",
        "Responsibilities": [
                    {
                        "ResponsibilityId":1,
                        "Responsibility":"Find requirements",
                        "description":"It is the practice of finding the requirements"
                    }
                    ]
}

]
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { ServicesModule } from './services/services.module';
import { TestimonialModule } from './testimonial/testimonial.module';
import { PersonModule } from './person/person.module';
import { FormModule } from './form/form.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CardModule } from 'primeng/card';
import { DemographicComponent } from './person/demographic.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './person/contact.component';
import {DataListModule} from 'primeng/datalist';
import { EduQualificationComponent } from './person/eduqualification.component';
import {SidebarModule} from 'primeng/sidebar';
import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar';
import { LoginFormComponent } from './authentication/loginform.component';
import { LoginFormModule } from './authentication/loginform.module';
import {AutoCompleteModule} from 'primeng/autocomplete';
import {Validators,FormControl,FormGroup,FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {Message,SelectItem} from 'primeng/api';
import {ReactiveFormsModule}    from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
 imports: [CommonModule,BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, AutoCompleteModule , AppRoutingModule, HomeModule, ServicesModule, CardModule,
 TestimonialModule,PersonModule,FormModule,LoginFormModule,DataListModule,SidebarModule,CalendarModule,FormsModule, SharedModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

project.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="let project of projects; let i=index">
    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6"><b>Project no {{i+1}}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Customer Name:</div>
    <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6"> {{ project.CustomerName }}</div> 
    <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Responsibility: </div>
    <div *ngIf="let item of projects.Responsibilities;">
        <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6">
           <p>Id  {{ item.Responsibility }} </p>                          
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">description:</div>
           <p>Id  {{ item.description }} </p>       
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please tell how can we access array within array means inside array.Thank you.

Comment: Responsibilities array is inside projects array so you have to iterate it like  *ngFor="let pro of Projects. Responsibilities

Comment: Iam upadted my answer please try again once.I resolved my mistake

Comment: No change this line <div *ngIf="let project of projects; let i=index">
to <div *ngFor="let project of projects; let i=index">. For reference see my answer again iam updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looking wrong.You can't access `this.projects` in html page.It's wrong.You can just modify these are things,

**First way:-**

**Note:-**
         While your json project Array Responsibilities is an array you can use like this(using two loops))

```
<div *ngFor="let project of projects; let i=index">
        <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6"><b>Project no {{i+1}}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Customer Name:</div>
        <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6"> {{ project.CustomerName }}</div> 
        <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Responsibility: </div>
        <div *ngIf="let item of projects.Responsibilities;">
            <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6">
               <p>Id  {{ item.Responsibility }} </p>                          
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">description:</div>
               <p>Id  {{ item.description }} </p>       
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Second way:-** 
    **Note:-**
    While your json project Array Responsibilities is an single array you can use like this(using [0] index))

```
<div *ngFor="let project of projects; let i=index">
        <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6"><b>Project no {{i+1}}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Customer Name:</div>
        <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6"> {{ project.CustomerName }}</div> 
        <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Responsibility: </div>            
        <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6">
               <p>Id  {{ projects.Responsibilities[0].Responsibility }} </p>                          
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">description:</div>
              <p>Id  {{ projects.Responsibilities[0].description }} </p>       
        </div>           
</div>
```

Iam making sample using sample tags. You can modify your convenient.Let try this once and let me know if any error.

I hope it's solve your problem.

Edit:-

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],  
})
```

import this things in app.module.ts file

Sorry i am updated my answer pls try again first way

Comment: I got this error at ngif.error is Can't bind to 'ngIfOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.I am using your first method.what should I do now?

Comment: Hey you have to import this things in app.module.ts file

Comment: Follow this link iam updated my answer please visit,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058075/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div

Comment: import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; i have imported this module but its not working still i am getting same error do i need to import any other module

Comment: note also spell mistake changed in div line see <div *ngFor="let project of projects; let i=index">

Comment: I imorted these things see my question updates is it correct or not?still same error is there

Comment: <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="let responsibility of projects.Responsibilities;">
I got error here

Comment: see iam changed this line my answer is <div *ngFor="let responsibility of projects.Responsibilities;">

Comment: change *ngIf to *ngFor

Comment: error gone but it doesnt show any record for responsibilities

Comment: Glad to help you