# Why do ng-if don't work inside a mat-dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-if

I have created a mat-dialog component to fire for http response. When I include a ngIf statement inside the html for the mat-dialog,it is not handled. On the console it shows a warning as follows.

**Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.**

NgIf works fine in all other components in the project.

Calling for mat-dialog inside typescript file.

```
 this.matDialog.open(PaymentModelComponent, {
              width: "630px",
              data: { message: response.comment },
              autoFocus: false,
              height: "630px",
            });
```

html code

```
<div *ngIf="true"><p>Show this only if "show" is true</p></div>
```

Why do ng-if don't work inside a mat-dialog ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058075/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div)

Comment: No,it didn't work. I tried it earlier.

Comment: Are you sure your modal component is in the correct module? And that it imports `BrowserModule`/`CommonModule`?

Comment: I am not sure I undestood earlier comment correctly. I am bit new to angular. BrowserModule and CommonModule are used as imports in the app.module.ts. I have used MyDialogModel as a  entryComponents . Is it okay?

Comment: Hello, have you find the solution? Cause I get the same case with you.
Thanks...

Comment: I found the reason.I will post it as the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All I needed to do was to add the DialogComponent to the module's declarations:

```
declarations: [..., MyDialogComponent]
```

No need to have the component code in the same file.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is add the dialogs to your module imports & declarations. In the same module where the component your dialogs are declared in is declared.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this hoping that someone may find it useful. This is not the exact answer for this problem, but this is how I overcome my scenario. In my case I was using mat-dialog component as an entry component inside the app.module.ts

```
 entryComponents: [ErrorComponent, UserAccountInfoReloadPopupDialogComponent],
```

For some reason, ng-if it is not working inside the dialog. It is not only for ng-if, all others like ng-for were not available.

I fixed the issue by defining both components in the same ts file.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-account-info",
  templateUrl: "./account-info.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./account-info.component.css"],
})
export class AccountInfoComponent implements OnInit {
//code
}

@Component({
  selector: "user-account-info-reload-popup-dialog",
  templateUrl: "./payment-modal.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./payment-modal.component.css"],
})
export class UserAccountInfoReloadPopupDialogComponent implements OnInit {
//code
}
```

Then I defined the newly created mat-dialog component inside angular module declaration.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: 
[
UserAccountInfoReloadPopupDialogComponent
],
```

This fixed my issue. You can check the angular mat-dialog documentation.
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview