# Problems with ngif

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a div at the top of a contact page that is supposed to show a success message after the user hits send. However Ngif doesn't appear to be respecting the condition that I have set. I'm kind of at a loss for what is happening here. Please help me find out why this isn't working. Code is below:

Html file

```
<h1>Contact</h1>
<div *ngIf="modalOpen" class="modalBox">
  <div class="modal">
    <h1 class="successMessage">Message Sent!</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="contact animate__animated animate__rotateInUpLeft">
  <form
    ngNativeValidate
    class="contact-form container"
    (submit)="sendEmail($event)"
  >
    <input
      type="text"
      name="name"
      placeholder="Name"
      class="form-control"
      required
    />
    <input
      type="email"
      name="email"
      placeholder="Email"
      class="form-control"
      required
    />
    <textarea
      class="message"
      name="message"
      placeholder="Message"
      class="form-control"
      required
    ></textarea>
    <button class="button" type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import emailjs, { EmailJSResponseStatus } from 'emailjs-com';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css'],
})
export class ContactFormComponent implements OnInit {
  modalOpen = false;

  public sendEmail(e: Event) {
    e.preventDefault();
    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        'service_692xmee',
        'template_08mwokp',
        e.target as HTMLFormElement,
        'user_fho8Bk2ef5EPCShODrioc'
      )
      .then(
        (result: EmailJSResponseStatus) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
    this.success();
  }

  success() {
    this.modalOpen = true;

    setTimeout(() => (this.modalOpen = false), 3000);
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

App module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProjectsComponent } from './projects/projects.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav'
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar'
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list'
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProjectsComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    BlogComponent,
    AboutComponent,
  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatToolbarModule, 
    MatListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
   
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: What behaviour do you observe? Your code works fine for me. Any errors in log? See code in action https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvoltk?file=src/app/app.component.ts
I suspect error in your css

Comment: Yes as a matter of fact I am getting an error in the console.

Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: Show us your module definition. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058075/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div

Comment: Ok i updated the post to show module

Comment: Omg, I found the issue. Contact component wasn't imported in app.module.ts

Comment: Good work! Also, the cli has a tool to generate new components, it remebers to add them in the module. See https://angular.io/cli/generate#component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the answer found during discussion (in comments under OP):

- `*ngIf` resulted in an error
- the error was reported in the console:

```
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'
```

- This lead to link [Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058075/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div)
- `ContactFormComponent` was not declared in the `@NgModule`.