# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property

Tags: angular, angular-module

My angular application run smoothly most of the times but it sometime fail at startup with messages like

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.

As already stated at [Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39058075/3520621) the issue is that the `CommonModule` is not imported. I'm probably doing something wrong but it seems the `CommonModule` is imported (if not it would never work, else it's working 90% of the time).

Here is my configuration:

#### app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NavigationModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    AngularSvgIconModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
      // Inspired by https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/how-to-build-an-angular-app-once-and-deploy-it-to-multiple-environments/#solution-3-mount-configuration-files-from-environment
      // Load configuration file.
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (envConfigService: EnvironmentService) => async () => envConfigService.loadConfiguration(),
      deps: [EnvironmentService],
      multi: true
    },
    CookieService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CacheInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MyHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    I18n,
    Xliff,
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translationsEn },
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' },
    { provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: CustomMatPaginatorIntl },
    CookieService,
    OverlayModule,
    DeviceDetectorUtils,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

#### app-routing-module.ts

All the application is on a single route (`/home`) which dynamically update components.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, loadChildren:  () => {
    return import('./features/feature1/feature1.module').then(m => m.Feature1Module),
           import('./features/feature2/feature2.module').then(m => m.Feature2Module),
           //...
           import('./navigation/navigation.module').then(m => m.NavigationModule),
           import('./features/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule);
  }},
  { path: 'password-creation/:m/:p', component: PasswordCreationComponent , loadChildren:  () => {
    return import('./features/user-management/user-management.module').then(m => m.UserManagementModule);
  }},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'prefix' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

#### home.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, SharedModule, HomeRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

#### home-routing-module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

#### shared.module.ts

```js
const PIPES = [
  // All my shared pipes
];

const COMPONENTS = [
  // All my shared components
];

const DIRECTIVES = [
  // All my shared directives
];

const MODULES = [
  CommonModule,
  PortalModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormsModule,
  LayoutModule,
  RouterModule,
  // All my shared modules
];

const PROVIDERS = [
  // All my shared providers
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...PIPES, ...COMPONENTS, ...DIRECTIVES],
  imports: [...MODULES],
  exports: [...PIPES, ...COMPONENTS, ...DIRECTIVES, ...MODULES],
  providers: [...PROVIDERS]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Every feature module imports the `sharedModule`.

I'm guessing this is due to lazy loading but the `CommonModule` and `BrowserModule` are imported in the `AppModule` so they should not be lazy loaded, right?

#### ng version

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.15
Node: 14.16.1      
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.13
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core               9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics         9.1.15
@angular/cdk                       9.2.4
@angular/cli                       9.1.15
@angular/material                  9.2.4
@angular/material-moment-adapter   11.2.13
@ngtools/webpack                   9.1.15
@schematics/angular                9.1.15
@schematics/update                 0.901.15
rxjs                               6.5.5
typescript                         3.8.3
webpack                            4.42.0
```

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Have you tried checking that a) You've included the correct spelling/syntax of ngIf and b) You've restarted your server before making that change to your module? Every time I encounter this issue I suspect it's some fundamental then realise I've written "ngif" isntead of "ngIf"

Comment: a) Yes I've checked. And as I said the application run smoothly most of the times, if it was a syntax error it would always fail. b) Yes I tried and it's not the issue. The issue may disappear after a restart but it also may not. In order to make the issue disappear I can refresh the browser page (sometime I need to refresh it more than once until the issue is gone).

Comment: @MHogge is this an Angular 12 app? Very similar thing started happening to me when I transitioned from Angular 8 to Angular 12.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard No I'm on version 9.1.15. Did you find a solution to your issue ?

Comment: @MHogge - I actually deleted the whole `@angular/cli` and removed the`node_modules` and did a fresh install. I never figured out what might be a cause of that issue.

Comment: Does your CLI version match your core version?

Comment: @Alex No. And I previously gives the wrong Angular version. I update the question with the full output of `ng version`.