# NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of '[component selector]'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a page, *SearchPage*, nested within my main page at the project's root, *HomePage*, and within *SearchComponent* are two child components: *PromptComponent* and *ResultsComponent*. Here's the `tree` output:

```
src/app/home/
├── home.module.ts
├── home.page.html
├── home.page.scss
├── home.page.spec.ts
├── home.page.ts
├── home-routing.module.ts
└── search
    ├── prompt
    │   ├── prompt.component.html
    │   ├── prompt.component.scss
    │   ├── prompt.component.spec.ts
    │   └── prompt.component.ts
    ├── results
    │   ├── results.component.html
    │   ├── results.component.scss
    │   ├── results.component.spec.ts
    │   └── results.component.ts
    ├── search.module.ts
    ├── search.page.html
    ├── search.page.scss
    ├── search.page.spec.ts
    ├── search.page.ts
    └── search-routing.module.ts
```

If I create another page with routing (or component, doesn't matter) within home, enter that route in the address bar, and then navigate to `/search`, I see the right content and it works fine without errors. However, if I refresh the page from there, or enter `/search` in the address bar, I get two console errors:

```js
NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'app-prompt'. core.js:10105
NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'app-results'. core.js:10105
```

This is referring to a couple of tags within *search.page.html:*

```html
<app-prompt
  (queryEmitter)="update($event)"
  *ngIf="query === ''"
></app-prompt>
<app-results
  [query]="query"
  (queryEmitter)="update($event)"
  *ngIf="query !== ''"
></app-results>
```

When I see errors, these components don't get rendered.

When they do work, here's *how* they work. First, an empty prompt is displayed in `<app-prompt>`. Later, when the user types something in the prompt, the value of `query` gets passed from an event emitter to *SearchPage*, and passed again to *ResultsComponent*.

The rest of the code is below. How do I get this to work in every case?

*search.page.ts*

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

/**
 * Main component for the search page and parent to `PromptComponent` and
 * `ResultsComponent`.
 *
 * @decorator `@Component({ selector: 'app-search', templateUrl: './search.page.html', styleUrls: ['./search.page.scss'], })`
 *
 * @alpha
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.page.scss'],
})
export class SearchPage implements OnInit {
  /**
   * Holds the value of `ion-searchbar` within each of the child components,
   * and allows for communication across components.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  query!: string;

  /**
   * Constructor for the search page.
   *
   * @param _route `ActivatedRoute`
   * @param _location `Location`
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _location: Location) {}

  /**
   * A lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has initialized all
   * data-bound properties of a directive. Takes query parameter from URL and
   * stores it locally.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      const query: null | string = paramMap.get('query');
      this.query = query ? query : '';
    });
  }

  /**
   * Method to update the `query` property and the URL.
   *
   * @param query String from search bar to be used in child components.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  update(query: string): void {
    this.query = query;
    this._location.replaceState(`search${query ? '/' + query : ''}`);
  }
}
```

*prompt.component.ts*

```js
import {
  AfterViewChecked,
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Output,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { SearchbarChangeEventDetail } from '@ionic/core/dist/types/components/searchbar/searchbar-interface.d';

/**
 * Prompt component. Child component of Search page responsible for prompting
 * the user and indirectly passing data to its sibling component, Results, with
 * the help of Word page.
 *
 * @selector `@Component({ selector: 'app-prompt', templateUrl: './prompt.component.html', styleUrls: ['./prompt.component.scss'], })`
 *
 * @alpha
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-prompt',
  templateUrl: './prompt.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prompt.component.scss'],
})
export class PromptComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  /**
   * Emitter object for passing query (text) value to the parent component for
   * its use and use by ResultsComponent.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  @Output() queryEmitter = new EventEmitter<string>();

  /**
   * Reference to `ion-searchbar` element to be set to focus.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  @ViewChild('searchbar') searchbar: HTMLIonInputElement;

  query:string;

  /**
   * Constructor that takes no arguments and does nothing.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  constructor() {}

  /**
   * An Angular lifecycle hook that is called after the default change detector
   * has completed checking a component's view for changes. This method simply
   * calls setFocus() on the searchbar element.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.searchbar.setFocus();
  }

  /**
   * Takes `ion-searchbar` value from template and emits it to the parent
   * component.
   *
   * @param $event The `ionChange` event object passed in via template.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  onChange($event: CustomEvent<SearchbarChangeEventDetail>): void {
    this.queryEmitter.emit($event.detail.value);
  }
}
```

*results.component.ts*

```js
import {
  AfterViewChecked,
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { IonSearchbar } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SearchbarChangeEventDetail } from '@ionic/core/dist/types/components/searchbar/searchbar-interface.d';

/**
 * Results component. Child component of Search page responsible for taking in
 * user input and displaying search results. Currently, though, all it does is
 * take in input and switch to its sibling component, Prompt, when the input is
 * cleared.
 *
 * @selector `@Component({ selector: 'app-results', templateUrl: './results.component.html', styleUrls: ['./results.component.scss'], })`
 *
 * @alpha
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  templateUrl: './results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results.component.scss'],
})
export class ResultsComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  /**
   * Query text passed in from parent component, which receives it either from
   * the `:query` URL parameter or from `PromptComponent`.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  @Input() query: string;

  /**
   * Emitter object for passing query (text) value to the parent component for
   * its use.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  @Output() queryEmitter = new EventEmitter<string>();

  /**
   * Reference to `ion-searchbar` element to be set to focus.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  @ViewChild('searchbar') searchbar: IonSearchbar;

  /**
   * Constructor that takes no arguments and does nothing apart from returning
   * the component instance.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  constructor() {}

  /**
   * Ionic lifecycle hook that gets called when the component is about to enter
   * view. Here, the search results are updated.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.search();
  }

  /**
   * Angular lifecycle hook called after calls to ngAfterContentChecked() have
   * finished. This hook simply calls setFocus() on the searchbar element.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.searchbar.setFocus();
  }

  /**
   * Takes `ion-searchbar` value from template and stores it locally. Then it
   * checks for an non-empty string, and if that passes, the search results are
   * updated. Finally, it emits the query value to the parent component, empty
   * or not.
   *
   * @param $event The `ionChange` event object passed in via template.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  onChange($event: CustomEvent<SearchbarChangeEventDetail>): void {
    const query = $event.detail.value;
    this.query = query;

    if (query) {
      this.search();
    }

    this.queryEmitter.emit(query);
  }

  /**
   * Emits a blank query value to the parent component so focus is returned to
   * PromptComponent.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  clear(): void {
    this.queryEmitter.emit('');
  }

  /**
   * Skeleton code for search functionality. Currently, it is used to log the
   * local value of `query` for debugging purposes.
   *
   * @alpha
   */
  private search(): void {
    console.log(this.query);
  }
}
```

**Edit**

*app.module.ts*

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*home.module.ts*

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

*search.module.ts*

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { SearchPageRoutingModule } from './search-routing.module';

import { SearchPage } from './search.page';
import { PromptComponent } from './prompt/prompt.component';
import { ResultsComponent } from './results/results.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    SearchPageRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [SearchPage, PromptComponent, ResultsComponent]
})
export class SearchPageModule {}
```

Other questions are solved by adding `CommonModule`, to *.module.ts, but as you can see above, that's already included.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058075/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div)

Comment: I think this question is duplicated, the problem maybe because you didn't import `Common Module` to your Module

Answer (score 2):

PLease go to the correct module.ts file of your project and check if you have imported the `CommonModule` .

Otherwise, import it as

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

Then, add it to the import array.

```
 @NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],    // Import here
  ...
})
class YourModule {}
```

Comment: `CommonModule` is already imported in _home.module.ts_ and _search.module.ts_. It was missing from _app.module.ts_, but adding it did not fix the issue. What else can I try? Including @vicnoob who had the same suggestion.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy   Could you post the three module.ts files ?

Comment: module.ts files posted.

Comment: That's how it was set up originally.