# Check field exist and based on that show data in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have multiple if else in my code like below

```
<td>
            <div *ngIf="data?.IsUser; else recentView"> 
            <span span *ngIf="data.user=='primary'; else userType">{{data.Name}}</span>
            <ng-template #userType>
              {{data.Name}}
            </ng-template>
          </div>
          <ng-template #recentView>{{ data.Name }} </ng-template> 
          </td>
```

but getting

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

If `data?.IsUser` key not exist then show `<ng-template>` block

any solution Thanks

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058075/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div ?

Comment: @JohnDoe No my case is different

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ng-template`, you should use `ng-container`. I think that it will help you to solve the above problem.

```
<td>
  <ng-container *ngIf="data?.IsUser; then listView; else recentView"></ng-container>
  
  <ng-template #listView>
    <ng-container *ngIf="data.user=='primary'; then primary; else userType"></ng-container>
  
    <ng-template #primary>
      <!-- Your code -->
    </ng-template>
  
    <ng-template #userType>
      <!-- Your code -->
    </ng-template>
  
  </ng-template>
  
  <ng-template #recentView>
    <!-- Your code -->
  </ng-template>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

This means your module does not have a import statement for `CommonModule`

You should add

```
import {CommonModule} from @angular/core
```