# Angular does not detect properties of html tags like <div [ngSwitch]='x'></div>. Angular is not woriking on my computer?

Tags: angular, typescript, config

I've worked with angular for the past 6 months without mayor problems. A few weeks ago I completed the first angular project that I first worked at, after that we started a new one. I cloned the repo, did npm install and started creating a few modules and components. The thing is that when I tried to use ng switch or ngIf the terminal would say: "Can't bind to 'NgSwitch/ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'". I'm sure it is not a code error since I've already imported CommonModule into my module and BrowserModule into the app.module.ts. I already uninstalled and reinstalled angular from my computer (angular material is also installed on the project). I also noticed that my old project that worked just fine a few days ago, also stopped working. Do you have any other ideas of what it could be?

As I already said, I tried reinstalling the project and angular itself. I also tried npm cache clean --force and then rebuild with ng serve. It still does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058075/cant-bind-to-ngif-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div)