# Angular2 (final version) *ngFor in component: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, ngfor

I started using Angular2 (final version) and i'm having some problems with *ngFor.

I've built the following component tree:
main -> dashboard -> alerts

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
>
> ("<div class="item" [ERROR ->]  *ngFor="let alert of alerts">
>       
>       "): DashboardAlertsComponent@5:20 Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template.
>
> Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all
>   directives are listed in the "directives" section.

It works ok but when i'm tried adding *ngFor loop in alerts component I got the following error:

**DashboardAlertsComponent**:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Alert} from "../../shared/models/alert.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard-alerts',
  templateUrl: './alerts.component.html'
})
export class DashboardAlertsComponent implements OnInit {

  alerts:Alert[] = new Array<Alert>();
  constructor() {
    this.alerts.push(new Alert('1', 'high', 'My alert1', '12/11/2016 4:50 PM'));
    this.alerts.push(new Alert('2', 'low', 'My alert2', '11/11/2016 9:50 PM'));
    this.alerts.push(new Alert('3', 'medium', 'My alert3', '10/11/2016 2:50 PM'));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**alerts.component.html**

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let alert of alerts">
    <span class="priority {{ alert }}"></span>
    <span class="title">{{ alert }}</span>
    <span class="time">3:40 PM</span>
    <a href="#" class="more-actions"><span>Actions</span></a>
</div>
```

**DashboardModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardAlertsComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  directives: [],
})
export class DashboardModule {
}
```

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DashboardModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

P.S I read many suggested solutions for this problem but none of them solved this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228971/cant-bind-to-ng-forof-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-property/34229918#34229918

Answer (score 12):

You should import `CommonModule` in the main module, and `BrowserModule` in the other modules (if you are working with multiple modules). I got the same problem and it works fine for me

Comment: you sure about this? i've done the opposite (BrowserModule in main module and CommonModule in the child module) and it worked, what is the correct way?

Comment: take a look here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-browser-vs-common-module

Comment: Yes you are right, I exchanged them. But I think it's the source of the problem :)

Comment: BrowserModule  for child component was my case

Comment: I believe this is wrong or outdated. The current contents of angular 2 docs ( the link provided above ) state that `BrowserModule` should only be imported in root module and `CommonModule` in all the rest.

Comment: Actually just opposite of it.

https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/28/angular2-error-cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property/