# Angular 12 template linting not working after switchting from tslint to eslint

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

After upgrading an nx workspace to v12, everything works as before, expected template linted in the IDE.

The IDE (WebStorm) shows some strange errors never happend before:
[image: linting erros after upgrading angular]

The first warning says *No directive is matched on attribute ngIf* even the `CommonModule` is imported, the second error related to the `async` says *Missing require() statement* and `var async = require('@angular/core/testing').async;`

It's really interesting, because building the whole monorepo works flawlessly so I guess this could be caused by some incorrect linting configuration. Have to say that the workspace was not just updated to the newest `nx` version, It was converted from `tslint` to `eslint` as well.

Did someone had similar issues in the past?

Comment: Do these show up if you run `nx lint some-project`? Or are they only showing up in IDE?

Comment: Seems like just showing up within WebStorm :/

Comment: I've got this issue too, even with a newly created angular project, did you find a fix?

Comment: I have the same issue here. It needs an update of AngularJS plugin, which bundles with the IDE (webstorm) version. So update IDE to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same ***No directive is matched on attribute ngIf*** message in PhpStorm, after updating a project to Angular 12. I created a new project with Angular CLI and had the same issue, while another project still on Angular 9 worked fine in the same IDE at the same time.

I did help > check for updates, and it said everything was up to date, but while looking on the JetBrains website I noticed there was a newer version of the Angular Plugin, that was bundled with a newer version of PhpStorm, that the auto update in the IDE had not found; I installed the new PhpStorm and the problem was fixed.

Currently using PhpStorm 2021.1.4

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on PyCharm. An update to 2021.3 RC solved the problem. It should also work on WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same on VS Code. The cause was in "Angular Language Service
" plugin, was need to restart it and the error disappear. So as mention above just go through extensions on your IDE and "restart/update or disable" it and check if error disappear.